# What's a hasContainer() in TinkerPop Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I recently stumbled upon the concept of `hasContainer`s, however I don't find much about what it is [in the documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/) and the [Practical Gremlin book](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html).

So what's a `hasContainer` and how and when is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the average user of Gremlin the `HasContainer` really shouldn't be of interest to you in building graph applications. The documentation you linked is meant for those types of users so that's why you won't find much about that in there. In fact, outside of the javadoc and the code itself I doubt you will really find it mentioned.

In answer your question though a `HasContainer` is a concept that only has relevance to those building TinkerPop graph implementations, typically in relation to query optimization when developing `TraversalStrategy` implementations. It is thus an internal concept to TinkerPop. The following won't make a lot of sense unless you're really tuned into this aspect of working with TinkerPop.

A `HasContainer` is constructed internally within certain Gremlin `Step` implementations like `HasStep` to hold the key and the `Predicate` from calls to `has(key, predicate)`. Rather than construct multiple `HasStep` objects for each call to `has()`, multiple `HasContainer` objects are constructed and are folded back into the same `HasStep`. For example:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name','bob').toString()
==>[GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(bob)])]
```

Note how the `toString()` representation of Gremlin above does not have two `HasStep` objects. It has the "GraphStep(vertex,[])" for `V()` and "HasStep([~label.eq(person), name.eq(bob)])" for `hasLabel('person').has('name','bob')`. The `hasLabel('person')` constructs the `HasStep` with a `HasContainer` for "~label.eq(person)" and then the next call to `has('name','bob')` doesn't bother with a new `HasStep`. It detects the previous one and folds it's `HasContainer` into that for "name.eq(bob)".

The `HasContainer` itself has some helper methods for working with the the key and the predicate as single object for convenience. Again, these are extreme internals for TinkerPop and you would likely not encounter them with normal usage.

Comment: Thanks @stephen-mallette! Then it's kind of what I thought it could be. Can you tell me how I can declare these has arrays in Java? I wan't to write a test for a QueryBuilder and have to declare the expected GraphTraversal. Currently I have `GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> expected = __.<Vertex>start().asAdmin().has("name","bob").has("age","35");` But that obviously doesn't match the optimized representation of that query...

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that your `QueryBuilder` produces a `GraphTraversal` and you need to assert it is the same as some "expected" `GraphTraversal`?

Comment: That's right. Currently I am declaring expected as a `String` literal and call `toString()` on the builder

Comment: i believe that you can just do a `equals()` on the `Traversal` object. you shouldn't have to compare internals. like, `__has("name","bob").has("age","35").equals(has("name","bob").has("age","35"))` is `true`